# How to map virtual path to physical path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I know I can get WebRoot by HostingEnvironment (Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting namespace).

I need to get a physical path according to a virtual path created in IIS within my web application. In IIS, the website root points to wwwroot of my published site and there is a **virtual directory** added in IIS which points to a folder outside of my wwwroot. I hope I can get the physical path of that **virtual directory**. In MVC 5 or earlier version, I can use HostingEnvironment.MapPath (System.Web namespace) or Server.MapPath, what should I do in MVC 6?

**EDIT:**

It's not the virtual path but the virtual directory added in IIS. I hope I can get the physical path of that virtual directory. I think virtual directory is a particular feature of IIS, which looks like a sub path of a full virtual path but can be a folder outside of physical web root folder.

**Oct 4, 2015**

Refer to [this issue in ASP.NET 5 Hosting repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/222), So far, it doesn't seem we can get the physical path of a virtual directory in IIS.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `IApplicationEnvironment` for that, which contains the property `ApplicationBasePath`

```
    private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment)
    {
        _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var rootPath = _appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think I can get a virtual directory defined in IIS by this way. ApplicationBasePath indicates the root path of my `wwwroot`, but the virtual directory can be completely a different path outside of my wwwroot although the virtual directory url itself looks like a subfolder of my website.

Comment: `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath` is exactly physical directiry of your application root (not wwwroot of IIS). It's a directory with app's project.json.
`IHostingEnvironment.WebRoot` is a subdirectory of ApplicationBasePath for your webroot - it's a dir specified in app's project.json as `webroot`. For an example it's a dir where StaticFilesMiddleware serves files from.

Answer (score 6):

On Azure Web Apps, you'll find the `wwwroot` is in a different place:

All of the source code gets copied to `D:/Home/site/approot/src/{WebsiteName}` except the `wwwroot`. `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath` points here.

The `wwwroot` goes in `D:/Home/site/wwwroot`. `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` points here.

It still won't work with IIS virtual directories. There is a `WebRootFileProvider` property on the `IHostingEnvironment` interface which provides an `IFileProvider` with methods like `GetFileInfo(string subpath)`. I read the [code](https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical/PhysicalFileProvider.cs) and found `subpath` is a physical one, not a virtual one.

Obviously, in a self-hosted setup, there is no IIS. If you rely on IIS and really must do this, you'll probably have to reference System.Web.

HTH.