# How to consistently get application base path for ASP.NET 5 DNX project on both production and development environment?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I have deployed a ASP.NET MVC 6 website to Azure from Git. Details of the deployment can be found in [this blog post](http://devonburriss.me/aspnet-vsonline-ci/) but basically I use DNU to publish it and then kudu to push it to an Azure website.

Using `IHostingEnvironment` I get the ApplicationBasePath. The problem is that the paths I get back are very different on localhost and on Azure.

Azure: "D:\home\site\approot\src\src"
Localhost: "C:\Users\deebo\Source\mysite\site\src"

I want to use the base path to get the full path to a folder containing some images: wwwroot/img/gallery/

I got around this with the following code:

```
var rootPath = _appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;

var pathFix = "../../../";
if(_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    pathFix = string.Empty;
}
var imagesPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, pathFix, "wwwroot", "img", "gallery");
```

This may work but seems hacky.

Is it possible my deployment method impacts on this?
Is there a more consistent way to get the application path?

Comment: What do you want to do with the application path? How does it influence your application?

Comment: I want to use the base path to get the full path to a folder containing some images: wwwroot/img/gallery. Added this to question. The path can also be seen in the code. Thanks for helping me make my question clearer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/IHostingEnvironment.cs#L25). From the Asp 5 [deep dive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn913182.aspx):

> The `IHostingEnvironment` services gives you access to the Web root path
>   for your application (typically your www folder) and also an
>   IFileProvider abstraction for your Web root.

So you can get the wwwroot path or even directly map a path:

```
var wwwrootPath = env.WebRootPath;
var imagesPath = hostingEnv.MapPath("img/gallery");
```

PS. I tried this locally, not on Azure. However I haven't found any mention about issues in Azure. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32192675/1836935) even mentions that in Azure `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` will point to `D:/Home/site/wwwroot`.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. Worked across Windows and Mac localhost as well as on Azure.

Comment: Good, and great to know it works on every environment!

Comment: Great info; (at least as of ASP.NET Core 1.0.0-RC2) you can obtain a reference to an `IHostingEnvironment` instance from any controller by declaring that controller's constructor with a parameter of this type; e.g., `public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env) { ...`

Comment: This is also how you would obtain the application's `ContentRootPath`, for anything you are packaging outside the publicly accessible `WebRootPath`. As mklement0 mentions, Dependency Injection is a great way to obtain the `IHostingEnvironment`, which also includes info like whether the app is running in Dev or Prod.