# ASP.NET MVC 6 application's virtual application root path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I get the virtual root path of the application on the server?

In another words: how can I do the following in ASP.NET MVC 6?

> [HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082888/asp-net-mvc-6-applications-virtual-application-root-path

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631066/how-to-consistently-get-application-base-path-for-asp-net-5-dnx-project-on-both)

Comment: @DanielJ.G., I did, it provides you with an absolute path to project's folder which is not what I need.

Comment: Can you not just use `@Url.Content("~/")`? I also just had a look at [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/UrlHelper.cs) and it is resolving "~" to the application path using `HttpContext.Request.PathBase`

Comment: @DanielJ.G., yes, I think you're right, though I can't find anywhere proper specification of the `PathBase` property. Please post your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need can be achieved with `@Url.Content("~/")`, which will map "~" to your virtual application root path.

Having a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/25eb50120eceb62fd24ab5404210428fcdf0c400/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/UrlHelper.cs#L175), it seems to do so using the `HttpContext.Request.PathBase` property:

```
public virtual string Content(string contentPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentPath))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (contentPath[0] == '~')
    {
        var segment = new PathString(contentPath.Substring(1));
        var applicationPath = HttpContext.Request.PathBase;

        return applicationPath.Add(segment).Value;
    }

    return contentPath;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following in MVC Core RC2:

Instead of `"~/something"` I use

Context.Request.PathBase + "/something"

or even more simply, just use `"/something"`, which means starting a path with a slash tells asp core to start from the root.

Comment: Thanks... Context.Request.PathBase worked and provided Virtual Directory Path