# How do I get the Web Root Path and the Content Root Path in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to add a root path as a parameter in a View, so I can pass it as a parameter to a PayPal button.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    ... snip ...

    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="@Model.UrlRoot/Manage/Subscription?userId=@Model.User.Id">

    ... snip ...
</form>
```

I was sifting through the answers at 
[How can I get my webapp's base URL in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288046/how-can-i-get-my-webapps-base-url-in-asp-net-mvc) (20 answers)
and
[ASP.NET MVC 6 application's virtual application root path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082888/asp-net-mvc-6-applications-virtual-application-root-path)

Since ASP.NET Core is quite different, the Request class no longer contains a .Url property, so most of those answers don't work.

Answer (score 11):

You can inject the IHostingEnvironment into the Controller like this:

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        protected readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {

        }
    }
```

In your _ViewImports.cshtml add:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
@inject IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment
```

Now you can use can use `HostingEnvironment` and all its properties in your form. 
For example `HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` or `HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`

Comment: You don't have to inject IHostingEnvironment into the controller if you just want to use it in a view.  InjectingIHostingEnvironment into _ViewImports makes sense, if you want it to be available in any View.  If you just need it in a single view, you can inject it directly into that view.

Comment: use `IWebHostEnvironment` in place of `IHostingEnvironment` for asp.net core 3.1 and later versions.

Answer (score 2):

I came across Marius Schulz's post. (If you are Marius, please add your answer, contact me and I'll remove mine.)

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/22/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core

For some reason my Controllers don't have the IHostingEnvironment injected in the constructor, but they do have the Request object.

In my Controller, I've declared

```
var urlRoot = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Url.Content("~")}";
```

and passed it to MyViewModel

```
var model = new MyViewModel { UrlRoot = urlRoot };
return View(model);
```

This takes into account http vs. https, port numbers, and hopefully, the site root if the web site is not rooted at /. Since my site is at / I cannot confirm that Url.Content("~") gets the site root.

Answer (score 2):

With .NET core 2.1 the context is automatically injected into views.
The base path of the request which displayed the view can be accessed like this:

```
@(Context.Request.PathBase)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a net core 5 razor page,  I added the following to the top of the page:

```
@inject IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment
```

then further down in my code, I used the following code with success:

```
string filePath = $@"{ hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath }\wwwroot\assets\img\users\{ user.ID }.jpg";

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        imageURL = $"{ user.ID }.jpg";
    }
```