# ASP 5 MVC 6 Server.MapPath equivalent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, server.mappath

Did someone know what is the equivalent of Server.MapPath (in MVC 5) in MVC 6 ?
Also did someone know a good website where all the difference is listed ? especially about controller method, because i need to do a controller who override method like onactionexecuting, etc

Thanks all

Comment: so no solution if i understand the duplicate ?

Comment: For me, solution is there => http://stackoverflow.com/a/28137835/5119765